# Windows RADIUS approval

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, nps

I'm in the process of rolling out WPA2 Enterprise and am trying to figure out how to allow mobile phones to use the network.

Pushing out the config is easy with my MDM, but how do I tell NPS to allow them?  I currently have a condition to allow all all domain-joined computers access, but that doesn't work for phones because they're not joined to the domain.

How do other people handle this?